# PHP's cURL taking a long time

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I have this PHP code to login to a remote website and extract some data:

```
$random=rand(1, 100000);
$cookie=$random . ".txt";
$agent="Mozilla/5.001 (windows; U; NT4.0; en-US; rv:1.0) Gecko/25250101";

function doRequest($method, $url, $referer, $agent, $cookie, $vars) {
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
if($referer != "") {
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
if ($method == 'POST') {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
}
if (substr($url, 0, 5) == "https") {
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
}
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($data) {
    return $data;
} else {
    return curl_error($ch);
}
}

function get($url, $referer, $agent, $cookie) {
return doRequest('GET', $url, $referer, $agent, $cookie, 'NULL');
}

function post($url, $referer, $agent, $cookie,  $vars) {
return doRequest('POST', $url, $referer, $agent, $cookie, $vars);
}
```

I execute the post function four times and the get function two times. The problem is that it takes forever to load and execute.

Comment: Are you sure it is not the server? Can you `ping` it?

Comment: Pretty impossible for us to tell you why remote server calls are taking a long time. Have you done any investigation to determine where the time is being spent?

Comment: You're initiating a new curl each tie you call your function, which means you're fully starting up a brand new curl and eliminate any chance of using HTTP 1.1 keepalives.

Comment: The server is responding fine to ping. The script, It takes around 3 minutes to load.